# Python: get name of file piped to stdin

Tags: python, filenames, stdin

I have a python program that reads input from stdin (required), and processes lines from stdin:

```
for lines in stdin:
     #do stuff to lines
     filename = #need file name
     #example print
     print(filename)
```

However, in this for loop, I also need to get the name of the file that has been piped in to this python program like this:

```
cat document.txt | pythonFile.py #should print document.txt with the example print
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you please give more information about why do you want to pipe the file name to the python script when you can pass the document file as an argument to the script?

Comment: @RushikeshGaidhani It's part of a school assignment. The instructions tells us we have to get input from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. As the receiving end of a pipe you have no knowledge where your data stream is coming from. The use of `cat` further obfuscates it, but even if you would write `./pythonFile.py < document.txt` you would have no clue.

Many unix tools accept filenames as argument and `-` as a special code for 'stdin'. You could design your script the same way, so it can be called like

- `cat document.txt | pythonFile.py -`  (your script doesn't know the input origin)
- `./pythonFile.py document.txt` (your script does know the file)

Comment: With `cmd < file` it is possible to determine the file from `/proc/self/fd/0`, but apparently this is a Unix-only solution.

Comment: @ypnos Okay, thank you for the help and info!